Does Magick obtained after getting Uncanny Fortitude increase maximum health?
The description for Hephaestus's Uncanny Fortitude Boon says

Gain bonus Max Life based on your Magick limit.

If I pick up an item that increases my Magick limit after getting Uncanny Fortitude, will it increase my Max Life? Or does the bonus only apply to Magick obtained before getting the Boon?

The effect of Uncanny Fortitude will activate as long as you own it, meaning any extra source of magick you will get after getting it will also count in the calculation to increase your maximum health.
